# Who was the Englishman working in 1818 at Mission San Carlos?

Tags: california, immigration, spanish-empire

Vasili Golovnin wrote in "Around the World on the *Kamchatka*":

> In the morning many of our officers and I went to the San Carlos Mission which is about five miles from Monterey on a small river and bay called Carmel.... The whole structure... also houses the storerooms and a workshop for making woolen blankets, which was started by an Englishman who is still managing it.

Who was the Englishman?

Comment: PS, yes, the idea that it may have been the Irish weaver Mulligan did occur to me.

Comment: The question is would the Russian writer you cite distinguish between English, Irish, and Scottish individuals.  If you can show he does, then it *might* be someone else. The text of one of my other answers does list two 'Englishmen', but Mulligan has already been established as a 'weaver'.

Comment: @user2448131 quite right. I only envisioned felted wool, but yes, the blankets could have been woven. At Golovnin's next stop, he mistook Kamehameha's English-Portuguese aide for a Scot. OK, I believe it was Mulligan.

Comment: In F. P. Lutke's account of the same visit, he describes an employee of the Mission as an Irishman, but adds that his companion Robson, "who knew him before, said that he was not an Irishman, but an Englishman...."